# Switching windows in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a simple game. I am currently creating a settings page, however when I try to go back to the home screen it doesn't do so. Could you please help me find my bug. Also I'm trying to keep each screen in a function and in my while loop I try to switch to different pages.

```
import tkinter as tk
win = tk.Tk()
win_state = False
font = ""


world=[ [0,0,0,1],
        [0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0],
        [2,0,0,0]]

def key(event):
    global pressed
    pressed = event.keysym

pressed = ""
screenMode = 0

def deleteallitems():
    for child in win.winfo_children():
        child.destroy()
def drawgrid():
    global win
    global win_state
    global canvas
    win.geometry("400x600")
    canvas = tk.Canvas(win, width = 410, height = 500)
    canvas.pack()
    for x in range(4):#ys
        for y in range(4):#xs
            canvas.create_rectangle(x*100+5,y*100+5,x*100+100+5,y*100+100+5)
            if(world[x][y]==1):
                canvas.create_oval(x*100+5,y*100+5,x*100+100+5,y*100+100+5,fill="Blue")
            elif(world[x][y]==2):
                canvas.create_rectangle(x*100+5+15,y*100+5+10,x*100+5+20,y*100+100+5-10,fill="green")
                canvas.create_rectangle(x*100+5+15,y*100+5+10,x*100+100+5-15,y*100+100+5-50,fill="green")
    win.bind("<Key>", key)
    button = tk.Button(win, text = "Click Me!", command= moveCharacter)    
    button.pack()
def moveCharacter():
    global pressed
    global win_state
    global win
    global world
    pressed = "none"
    while (pressed == 'none'):
        win.update()
    print("Keyed!!")
    print (pressed)
    breakloop = False
    for y in range(4):
        for x in range(4):
            if(world[y][x] == 1):
                world[y][x] = 0
                print("Found!!")
                try:
                    if(pressed=="Up"):
                        if(world[y][x - 1] == 2):
                            win_state = True
                            goToWinScreen()
                        world[y][x - 1]=1
                    if(pressed=="Down"):
                        if(world[y][x + 1]==2):
                            win_state = True
                            goToWinScreen()
                        world[y][x + 1]=1
                    if(pressed=="Right"):
                        if(world[y - 1][x]==2):
                            win_state = True
                            goToWinScreen()
                        world[y - 1][x]=1
                    if(pressed=="Left"):
                        if(world[y - 1][x]==2):
                            win_state = True
                            goToWinScreen()
                        world[y - 1][x]=1
                except:
                    world[y][x]=1

                    breakloop=True
                    break
            if(breakloop):
                break
    win.update()
def Draw():
    drawgrid() 
    deleteallitems()
def goToWinScreen():
    global screenMode
    screenMode = 2
def winScreen():
    can = tk.Canvas(win,width=500,height=500)
    can.pack()
    win.resizable(False,False)
    can.create_text(250,250,text = "You win!", fill = '#55B7FF', font = (font,60))
    can.configure(background='#7A5EFF')

    enterbutton = tk.Button(win, text="Home",command = changeToHome)
    enterbutton.configure(activebackground = '#7A5EFF', width=10, height=2)

    can.create_window(410/2,300,anchor = tk.NW, window = enterbutton)
    win.mainloop()

def drawStart():
    global win

    win.title("Home Screen")

    parent = tk.Frame(win)  

    win.resizable(False,False)
    win.geometry('400x400')

    title = tk.Label(win, text = "Simple Game", font=(font, 24, 'bold'))
    title.pack(fill="x", pady = "50")

    playButton = tk.Button(win, text="Play", width=10, command = changeToPlay)
    playButton.pack(fill = "y", pady = (0, 50))

    settingButton = tk.Button(win, text="Settings", width=10, command = changeToSettings)
    settingButton.pack(fill = "y")

    parent.pack(expand=1)
    win.mainloop()

def changeToSettings():
    global screenMode
    screenMode = 3

def changeToPlay():
    global screenMode
    screenMode = 1

def Settings():
    global fontfamily, win
    win = tk.Tk()
    win.geometry('400x400')
    win.title("Settings")
    fontfamily = tk.StringVar(win)
    fontfamily.set("Arial")
    fontFamilyMenu = tk.OptionMenu(win, fontfamily, "Arial", "Courier New", "Comic Sans MS", "Fixedsys", "MS Sans Serif", "MS Serif", "Symbol", "System", "Verdana")
    fontFamilyMenu.pack(pady = (25, 300))
    home = tk.Button(win,text="Home",command = changeToHome)
    home.pack()
    win.mainloop()
def changeToHome():
    global screenMode
    global font
    font = fontfamily.get()
    screenMode = 0

while 1:
    if(screenMode == 0):
        drawStart()
    if(screenMode == 1):
        Draw()
    if(screenMode == 2):
        winScreen()
    if(screenMode == 3):
        Settings()
    win.update()
```

Comment: What is your error?

Comment: There isn't an error it's just not doing anything

Comment: Have you run it through a debugger?  You might also try simplifying it - ask it to do much less, until you can find where it fails, and then build up from there.

Comment: What are "#xs" and "#ys"? (They seem to be commented out, but I'm curious about what they stand for.)

Answer (score 1):

How about you try to not use that while loop ?
I modified your code but its far from perfect:

```
import tkinter as tk

"""I am going to make a game to use arrow keys to move a character to a flag"""

font, win = "", ''      # Define win so you can use 'global' or you cna pass it by argument

world=[ [0,0,0,2],
        [0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0],
        [1,0,0,0]]


def drawgrid():
    global win
    canvas = tk.Canvas(win, width = 400, height = 400)
    for x in range(4):#ys
        for y in range(4):#xs
            canvas.create_rectangle(x*100+5,y*100+5,x*100+100+5,y*100+100+5)
            if(world[x][y]==1):
                canvas.create_oval(x*100+5,y*100+5,x*100+100+5,y*100+100+5,fill="Blue")
            elif(world[x][y]==2):
                canvas.create_rectangle(x*100+5+15,y*100+5+10,x*100+5+20,y*100+100+5-10,fill="green")
                canvas.create_rectangle(x*100+5+15,y*100+5+10,x*100+100+5-15,y*100+100+5-50,fill="green")
def drawStart():
    global win
    win = tk.Tk()
    win.title("Home Screen")

    parent = tk.Frame(win)  

    win.resizable(False,False)
    win.geometry('400x400')

    title = tk.Label(win, text = "Simple Game", font=(font, 24, 'bold'))
    title.pack(fill="x", pady = "50")

    playButton = tk.Button(win, text="Play", width=10)
    playButton.pack(fill = "y", pady = (0, 50))

    settingButton = tk.Button(win, text="Settings", width=10, command = changeToSettings)
    settingButton.pack(fill = "y")

    parent.pack(expand=1)
    win.mainloop()

def changeToSettings():
    win.destroy()           # Destroy win panel
    Settings()              # Call settings 

def Settings():
    global fontfamily, win
    win = tk.Tk()
    win.geometry('400x400')
    win.title("Settings")
    fontfamily = tk.StringVar(win)

    fontfamily.set("Arial")

    fontFamilyMenu = tk.OptionMenu(win, fontfamily, "Arial", "Courier New", "Comic Sans MS", "Fixedsys", "MS Sans Serif", "MS Serif", "Symbol", "System", "Verdana")
    fontFamilyMenu.pack(pady = (25, 300))

    home = tk.Button(win,text="Home",command = changeToHome)

    home.pack()

    win.mainloop()

def changeToHome():
    win.destroy()       # Destroy win panel
    drawStart()         # Call start window

drawStart()
```

Comment: A well designed tkinter app should create a single instance of `Tk`. While your code will work in this specific implementation, it's not the idiomatic way to write a tkinter program.

Comment: Of course, but i wonted to keep my modifications of the original code to minimum so that OP can understand it.

Comment: I need to use the loop so later I can delete all the elements on the window and then update the window to the final version

Comment: @SruthiKurada when you do `win.mainloop()` it enters the main event loop for tkinter so it can respond to events etc.  Implementing your own loop over top of it will *at best* slow down the responsiveness by a lot.  I'd highly suggest you try to use event callbacks to change the status of the program instead of a state variable.